# Closing questions constructed in such a way as to preclude normal answers

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

I see a number of questions each day on StackOverflow that read something like this:

> I would like to do Normal Programming Task A, but I cannot use X, Y, or Z library [which normally one would use to do A]. How do I accomplish this?

or:

> I would like to do Normal Programming Task A, but without importing anything or using any built-in functions.

These questions are extremely annoying to me personally, because they so frequently involve a long string of comments where we must try to cajole the OP into explaining *why* they have these absurd requirements, or what they have against using the well-tested solutions most of us would normally turn to. (These reasons are almost never given in the original question.)

Furthermore, answers are often given, downvoted, and revised in the face of the complex requirements, either because they were explained poorly or because the OP moves the goalposts with an "Oh, I actually can't do that either" comment.

Questions like this nearly inevitably lead to a huge mess, and require the attention of several commenters and editors before the question becomes properly answerable.

The close reasons I feel are currently most applicable to this are "Too Broad" or "Unclear What You're Asking". However, closing a question with one of these reasons doesn't leave in place a very helpful message for this situation.

Too broad says:

> There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

While technically correct, this does not address this specific recurring problem. Ironically, this text is too broad for providing proper instructions.

Unclear What You're Asking says:

> Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

This text is even less helpful. Here, we know exactly how the question should be clarified, but the automated text does not help us explain it.

I personally think a new close reason might be in order for this, but I have the feeling I might get some pushback on this if the community already feels the earlier mentioned close reasons are applicable. What do you think? How do you handle such questions?

Comment: _...they were explained poorly or because the OP moves the goalposts with an "Oh, I actually can't do that either" comment._ - Ignore my previous comment, this sounds more like a specific variation on [chameleon questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions). If the OP is editing their question in a way that invalidates existing answers, those edits should be rolled back.

Comment: @BSMP I was thinking of questions [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32319317/without-version-checking-or-six-how-can-i-use-except-myerror-e-vs-except#comment52513991_32319317). OP wants to know how to write code that is compatible with Python 2 and 3. **Except** without detecting what version of Python is running in any normal way (no reason given why). Oh, and [that awesome library just for this](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/six)? Forget it (also doesn't say why). Cue a bunch of, "but why not this? And this? and this?" until finally we hit upon one he "can" do (again, why?).

Comment: @BSMP Or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32486747/how-to-print-a-dictionary-without-using-sorted-modules#comment52834472_32486747). Let's sort in Python without using [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) and "without using modules", whatever that means to this person. Again, no reasons given, no clear requirements. We must chase it out in comments to find it is a pointless, "I want to do this but I don't even know where to start" beginner question.

Comment: These questions annoy me too - but if I get frustrated I just move on. There's no telling if someone in the future might find the question and any answers helpful. The internet is big, we don't have to close *every* question.

Comment: @MarkRansom Closing a question doesn't have to mean deleting and never answering it. It's no different than asking for a MCVE. It's closing the question with something to specifically say, "If you have extreme or unusual constraints, please spell them out explicitly in your question and explain your reasoning." A lot of these are also XY problems -- the OP is doing contortions because they got themselves in a bind with an earlier decision.

Answer (score 2):

This is just too narrow of a situation to merit its own close reason.  Either use one of the close reasons that you've mentioned and comment on the post to further clarify why it applies, or use a custom close reason to explain in your own words why the question merits closure.

Comment: I may just avoid all these types of questions. I feel like every time I do this, I get in a protracted argument about why the close reasons "don't apply" because they feel there is a specific answer (not too broad) or that it's very clear that they simply want to do it in a specific way. The reason I asked for maybe a better close reason is that I feel the system doesn't help me in any way here; rather, I have to expand on it and apologize that it is unclear.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist That's absolutely a position I can understand and respect.  I walk away from questions all the time because it's just too much work to try to help the OP fix it, and I just can't be bothered.  But the fact remains that this just isn't such a common problem as to merit its own close reason.